# What are the methods for infering genetic interactions?

Tags: genetics

Is there a classification of methods for inferring genetic interactions? I mean some work published, utilizes genetical genomics data.  Is this possible with expression data alone? And how about perturbation screens? I guess they all need information about mutants/genetic variations?

Comment: The questions is vague and difficult to answer because there "genetic interactions" is a catch-all bag for anything that isn't a monogenic trait - which is to say, most of them.

Answer (score 1):

BioGRID is an interaction database, and they catalogue interactions by (among other things) the class of experiment that discovered them. See http://wiki.thebiogrid.org/doku.php/experimental_systems#genetic_interactions

Other than that, you should look at recent reviews and publications, but you will easily get lost unless you figure out some important particulars, like:

- What species? Yeast, worm, human, cell line?
- What sort of interaction? Synthetic lethality? Complicated, fancy epistasis?
- How much? Genome-wide? 2-3 genes?